# Fresh installed image not booting

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

Technically a long-awaited update to a previous question of mine.

I have a brand new raspberry pi 4, with an official RP power supply. Brand new 32GB SD micro SD card.

Balena Etcher does not run on my Linux Mint machine (main machine) so I used dd to install the latest raspbian to the SD card:

```
sudo dd bs=1M if=~/Downloads/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 conv=fdatasync status=progress

6806306816 bytes (6,8 GB, 6,3 GiB) copied, 439,034 s, 15,5 MB/s 
6496+0 records in
6496+0 records out
6811549696 bytes (6,8 GB, 6,3 GiB) copied, 452,661 s, 15,0 MB/s
```

It completed with no errors.

when I insert the SD card into my main machine and run `lsblk` I see:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29,7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /media/jess/boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   6,1G  0 part /media/jess/rootfs
```

The SD card is not empty, it is full of boot files etc.:

```
/media/jess/rootfs $ ls
bin   dev  home  lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr

/media/jess/boot $ ls
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb         bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb  fixup.dat         start4cd.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb    bootcode.bin         fixup_db.dat      start4db.elf
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb        cmdline.txt          fixup_x.dat       start4.elf
bcm2708-rpi-zero.dtb      config.txt           issue.txt         start4x.elf
bcm2708-rpi-zero-w.dtb    COPYING.linux        kernel7.img       start_cd.elf
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb       fixup4cd.dat         kernel7l.img      start_db.elf
bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb       fixup4.dat           kernel8.img       start.elf
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb       fixup4db.dat         kernel.img        start_x.elf
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb  fixup4x.dat          LICENCE.broadcom
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb       fixup_cd.dat         overlays
```

When I insert it into my Pi and power it up, the red LED stays on, and the green LED does not flash, this indicates a booting issue I believe.

How can I diagnose this?

And at what point is it just easier to buy a pre-made SD card? Any recommendations because I can not continue like this?

Comment: Have you got a machine that Etcher will run on? It's the simplest option.

Comment: How do you know it's not booting. Create a file with `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt;touch /mnt/ssh;umount /mnt` and it will come up with ssh enabled.

Comment: @CoderMike sadly I don't :/

Comment: @Dougie I'll try yhat

Comment: See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: @CoderMike ... `dd` in linux will do exactly what `etcher` does in Windoze

Comment: I would suggest trying a difference SD card - if you haven't already

Comment: ok, let me rephrase ... the dd command as shown in the question works just like etcher ... because there's only full blocks (+0) and the fdatasync option has been given - except there's been no verification but that's easy enough to do

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I add verification?

Comment: verification isn't required for it to work ... but you could use `sum`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my Pi4 and was searching in the same direction as you did (with raspian-buster).
At the same time i had the Libreelec system with Kodi on  another card, which bootet without any problems - on the same Pi4!

In the end,  i found *my* answer here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558
(at the end of this post, pi4 boot problems are discussed)

I unplugged mouse and keyboard, plugged in the power - et voilá: it walked right through
Now my Raspian OS is up and running just fine.
Of course, i plugged mouse and keyboard back in, when it was up.

Comment: Maybe this is specific to this mysterious "Raspian OS"

Comment: Rudi, you need an _accent grave_ on voilà.

Comment: Thanks, I will try unplugging my mouse and keyboard first